# sql get username twice in one query

Tags: sql

I have the following 3 tables:

```
users:
id, username

folders:
id,fkuser(connects to user.id)

folder_comments:
id,fkuser(connects to user.id), fkfolder(connects to folder.id)
```

I want to get the commenter username(`folder_comments.fkuser->user.id<->user.username`) **AND** and the username of the folder owner (`folder_comments.fkfolder->folder.id<->folder.fkuser->user.id<->user.username`);

The query I have thoght of is partial:

```
SELECT `folder_comments`.*, `folder`.`fkuser` as folderuserid, `user`.`firstname` as username
FROM `folder_comments` 
                left join `folder` on `folder_comments`.`fkfolder` = `folder`.`id`
                left join `user` on `folder_comments`.`userid` = `user`.`id`
```

How can I get the folder's owner username?

edit :

I tried:

```
    SELECT `folder_comments`.*, `folder`.`fkuser` as folderuserid, `user`.`firstname` as username, , `user`.`firstname` as folderowner
        FROM `folder_comments` 
                        left join `folder` on `folder_comments`.`fkfolder` = `folder`.`id`
                        left join `user` on `folder_comments`.`userid` = `user`.`id`
left join `user` on `folder`.`fkuser` = `user`.`id`
```

but I get an error `Not unique table/alias: 'user'`

Comment: You _can_ join the same table (`users` in your case) multiple times, under different aliases, and with different join conditions.

Comment: Hi, I have tried that. see edit in the quetion's body.

Comment: Well, _both_ my comment, _and_ the error you're getting suggest that you _should_ alias your `user` table with a distinct name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use user in join multiple times, something like this:

```
select folder.*, userfolder.username, comment.*, usercomment.username
  from folders folder inner join
  user userfolder on folder.fkuser = userfolder.id inner join
  comments comment on comment.fkfolder = folder.id inner join
  user usercomment on comment.fkuser = usercomment.id
```

when using the same table multiple times in a join it's important you use different alias

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I get what's where in your schema

but you do it like this. This is get mum and dad's name from people

```
Select Child.Name,Mothers.Name, Father's.Name
From Child
Inner Join People Mothers On Child.MotherID = Mothers.PersonID
Inner Join People Fathers On Child.FatherID = Fathers.PersonID
```

So join to the table as many times as you need but give each one a different alias.